# Reading the input from a relay's NO output over 12 meters

Tags: relay, atmega, pullup

I want to read the input from my driveway gate beam using an Atmega32. I know the gate beam is powered with 12V DC which I get from the driveway gate motor's battery. The beam also has three outputs, Normally open (NO), Normally closed (NC), and COM using the relay. I have seen my gate receiver wired COM to the ground and the NO goes to the trigger to the gate's PCB. I want to use a similar way to trigger my Atmega32.

I will also be connecting my COM to the ground of the gate beam (and I know all grounding has to be common i.e. gate battery. gate beam and Atmega32). I will then run the NO output of the beam to my Atmega32. This means whenever the beam is broken NO will be connected to the ground. Now on my Atmega32, I will use a GPIO to detect this low state. Also, I will be pulling the GPIO to 5V DC using a pullup resistor.

My question is therefore: is this okay, or do I need more complicated circuitry to do this?

The second question is: the Atmega32 and the beam will be about 12 meters apart and so will the signal cable i.e. the NO cable from the gate beam to the Atmega32; will this length be an issue?

Comment: TTL level signal to 12 meters? You will get a lot of EMI. Current loop and twisted pair may work. Still some noise but you may filter some by programm. And  power supply for MCU does not need connection of grounds, use optocoupler.

Comment: @user263983 what do you mean by current loop, and on thje note of loops what is a ground loop?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop where did you see"ground loop"?

Comment: @user263983 I came across that term ground loop and thought that was what you meant but I see that is a whole new question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a relay output, then you don't have to connect all the grounds together unless you want to for other reasons.  The COM of the relay would only have to go to the Atmega32's ground.

You might get away with it running over 12m if you use a reasonably "strong" pull-up resistor to 5V.  Something like hundreds of ohms, instead of the usual kilohms.  The results may depend on the amount of electrical interference that the loop is subject to.  Run it well away from noisy power cables.

Comment: I am confused, why is the COM only going to the atmega? As mentioned when the beam is broken the relay switches from NC to NO, So COM should be connected to gnd or a voltage (12V in this case, since it is proesent on the input of the beam supply), and the NO or NC should then go to the atmega, since it is where the "trigger" is coming from..

Comment: @Joey what I meant is that the NO would be wired to the Atmega's GPIO input, and the relay COm to the Atmega's ground.

Answer (score 1):

Practically is much simpler than in theory. Here is one version. Current loop 10mA can be created by connecting resistor 1.2kOhm  to +12V, another side to line+ and NO of relay. Line- to ground and COM. Line is twisted pair, CAT3 for instance. Receiver is optotransistor, output to input MCU with pull-up resistor. Power supplies are different, grounds not necessary connect together. Could be different version too, in common, current goes through resistor and relay contacts.